# Speedlm update "need object with call component"

Tags: r, components, lm

I'm trying to use the update option of `speedlm` [(speedglm package)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/speedglm/speedglm.pdf) as I don't have enough RAM to calculate the whole model at once, and `biglm` only uses one CPU.
The code below is a reproducable example of what's going wrong.

```
library(speedglm)
formula <- Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width
chunk1 <- iris[1:10,]
chunk2 <- iris[11:20,]
chunk3 <- iris[21:30,]
lmfit <- speedlm(formula, chunk1)
lmfit <- update(lmfit, chunk2)
lmfit <- update(lmfit, chunk3)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
> lmfit <- speedlm(formula, chunk1)
> lmfit <- update(lmfit, chunk2)
> lmfit <- update(lmfit, chunk3)
Error in update.default(lmfit, chunk3) : 
  need an object with call component
>
```

If it would be due to having `update` instead of `updateWithMoreData` I would already expect the error after updating with chunk2.

Would like to know a way to fix this, or if I have to use an alternative.
Thanks in advance!

---

Getting the following errors using `updateWithMoreData`:

```
> lmfit <- speedlm(formula, chunk1)
> lmfit <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, chunk2)
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
> lmfit <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, chunk3)
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
>
```

---

The following code worked, props to @LyzandeR

```
> library(speedglm)
> chunk1 <- iris[1:10,]
> chunk2 <- iris[11:20,]
> chunk3 <- iris[21:30,]
> lmfit  <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, chunk1)
> 
> for (i in list(11,20, 21:30)){
+   lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, iris[i,])
+ }
> lmfit2
Linear Regression Model of class 'speedlm':

Call:  speedlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = chunk1) 

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     2.9876       0.5813  

>
```

Comment: Maybe you want `updateWithMoreData`? `update.speedlm` expects a formula as the second argument according to the documentation.

Comment: @Roland Thanks, I completely missed thatone in the documentation. However it doesn't fix the problem. Updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `update` to update your model you need to use `updateWithMoreData` as per @Roland's comment. There is a catch though.

If you use the code like this, you get:

```
library(speedglm)
formula <- Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width
chunk1 <- iris[1:10,]
chunk2 <- iris[11:20,]
chunk3 <- iris[21:30,]
lmfit <- speedlm(formula, chunk1)
#runs fine up to here

#but this gives an error
lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, chunk2)
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Apparently, this is caused because it tries to call this (from traceback):

`as.formula(object$call[[2]])`

which fails because `lmfit$call[[2]]` returns `formula`. However, if you change it to this it works:

```
library(speedglm)
chunk1 <- iris[1:10,]
chunk2 <- iris[11:20,]
chunk3 <- iris[21:30,]
#use the actual formula below so lmfit$call[[2]] will return it
#and now all the three lines below work fine
lmfit  <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, chunk1)
lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, chunk2)
lmfit3 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, chunk3)
```

Notice that when you print them, both will say they are chunk 1 because the call stays the same but the results are correct:

Output:

```
> lmfit2
Linear Regression Model of class 'speedlm':

Call:  speedlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = chunk1) 

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     1.8398       0.9181  

> lmfit
Linear Regression Model of class 'speedlm':

Call:  speedlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = chunk1) 

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     2.3882       0.7468
```

Comment: Sweet! Do you know how I could apply this in a loop with an x amount of updates?

Comment: It shouldn't be very difficult right? Just create the chunks before hand (or just the rows of the data.frame), then loop with sth like `for i in list(11:20, 21:30) updateWithMoreData(lmfit, iris[i,])`. Make sure you run `speedlm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width , data = iris[1:10,]) ` before starting the loop. This should work. Experiment using this and you can always post a new question in case you have trouble with it.

Comment: Only the lmfit <- speedlm() needs a different name from the lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(). See my question for how I've done it.